# Unexpected behaviour synchronisation using kill and pause libc calls

Tags: c, synchronization, signals, ipc, kill

I have a simple program that takes in an user input `N`, serially starts making `N-1` children, i.e, `ith` process is the child of `(i-1)th` process. Initially there is only one process, which creates a single child process, which in turn creates another child process, and so on.
After I have the N processes in place, I have to run a series of `SYN` and `ACK` commands, in a way that the child passes on `ACK` to the parent until we reach the first process, which then passes `SYN` to the child processes until we reach the last process. This cycle goes on for a specified number of iterations `max_itr`. Example at the end.
This is program I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int N, max_itr, itr, present_i, cid, pid;

void handler1()
{
    ++itr;
    if(itr > max_itr)
    {
        kill(cid, SIGUSR1);
        return;
    }
    printf("Syn:%d\t",getpid());
    if(present_i < N)
    {
        kill(cid, SIGUSR1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Ack:%d\n",getpid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    }
}

void handler2()
{
    if(present_i > 1)
    {
        printf("Ack:%d\n",getpid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    }
    else{
        ++itr;
        if(itr > max_itr)
        {
            kill(cid, SIGUSR1);
            return;
        }
        printf("Syn:%d\t",getpid());
        if(present_i < N)
        {
            kill(cid, SIGUSR1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&N);
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
    itr = 0;
    max_itr = 5; // fixed
    present_i = 1;
    // printf("%d\t%d\n",getpid(),present_i);
    while(present_i<N)
    {
        cid = fork();
        if(cid == 0)
        {
            present_i ++;
            // printf("%d\t%d\n",getpid(),present_i);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(present_i == N)
    {
        printf("Ack:%d\n",getpid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
        pause();
    }
    while(itr<=max_itr) pause();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using `SIGUSR1` signals to propagate `SYN` commands to the child processes and `SIGUSR2` signals to propagate `ACK` to the parent processes. But I am not getting the expected output, and the program is paused after the first iteration. I expect a output like this:

```
INPUT: N=3, max_itr=2
Processes created: 2341, 2342 (child of 2341), 2343 (child of 2342)
OUTPUT:
Ack:2343
Ack:2342
Ack:2341
Syn:2341    Syn:2342    Syn:2343
Ack:2343
Ack:2342
Ack:2341
Syn:2341    Syn:2342    Syn:2343
```

I have not been able to figure out the reason why this program hangs.

Comment: Why do you pause the signal handlers?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am using `pause()` to sleep the process till it receives an `ACK` (SIGUSR2 signal) or `SYN` (SIGUSR1 signal) to continue.

Comment: But why in the signal handlers? Shouldn’t they just handle the signal and return rather than wait for another signal before returning?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If I return in the signal handler, the process would end without waiting for the signal for the next iteration right?

Comment: No, the main is what matters. Signal handlers are run on signals and just handle it and return. They don’t affect the main function.

Comment: Hey @SamiKuhmonen I understood your point. I have moved my `pause()` statement to main. Now the program exits, but the output is not synchronised. Thanks for the suggestion btw. It was pretty obvious, my bad :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187305/discussion-between-yobro97-and-sami-kuhmonen).